# Parameter precision in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am using intel fortran 2016. I have defined some precision variables as follows:

```
 ! definition of single, double and quad precision
        integer, parameter :: SINGLE_PRECISION = selected_real_kind(6, 37)
        integer, parameter :: DOUBLE_PRECISION = selected_real_kind(15, 307) ! is used as standard precision
        integer, parameter :: QUAD_PRECISION = selected_real_kind(33, 4931)

        ! definition of variable precision for REAL, INTEGER
        integer, parameter :: REAL_TYPE = DOUBLE_PRECISION
        integer, parameter :: INTEGER_TYPE = 4
```

I would like to  now use these to control the precision of a parameter that gets declared in a subroutine as follows:

```
  SUBROUTINE SKIP(IUNIT,NBYTS)

  IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)
  Character c*1
  Parameter(n1 = 1024, nT1 = 8*n1)
```

I tried the following :

```
Parameter(INTEGER_TYPE)((n1 = 1024, nT1 = 8*n1)
Parameter(INTEGER_TYPE)((n1 = 1024, nT1 = 8*n1, kind = INTEGER_TYPE)
```

All to no avail. What is the proper way to define parameter precision in Fortran?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using modern Fortran with kinds, do not use implicit typing and parameter statements. Just define the type and the value of the parameter in one statement as shown in answers below (and the very same way you define your own kind parameters). And use IMPLICIT NONE, it will save you hours if not days of debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** this is essentially the same as [Francescalus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379472/8344060), but with some extra fluf.

The issue at hand here is related to the `IMPLICIT` statement.

The [Fortran standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) makes the following statements :

> **5.5 IMPLICIT statement**
>
> 1. In a scoping unit, an `IMPLICIT` statement specifies a type, and
>      possibly type parameters, for all implicitly typed data entities whose
>      names begin with one of the letters specified in the statement.
>      Alternatively, it may indicate that no implicit typing rules are to
>      apply in a particular scoping unit.
> 2. `<snip>`
> 3. In each scoping unit, there is a mapping, which may be null, between
>      each of the letters `A, B, ..., Z` and a type (and type parameters).
>      An `IMPLICIT` statement specifies the mapping for the letters in its
>      letter-spec-list. `IMPLICIT NONE` specifies the null mapping for all
>      the letters. If a mapping is not specified for a letter, the 
>      default for a program unit or an interface body is default integer if
>      the letter is `I, J`, ..., or `N` and default real otherwise, and the
>      default for an internal or module procedure is the mapping in the host
>      scoping unit.

So in short, by default everything is of type default `REAL` unless it starts with `I`,`J`,...,`N`, then it is of type default `INTEGER`.

In the example in the question, the variables `n1` and `nT1` are hence default `INTEGER` unless specified otherwise. Thus the following might be a solution :

```
subroutine skip(IUNIT,NBYTS)
   implicit double precision (A-H,O-Z)
   character c*1
   integer(kind=integer_kind), parameter :: n1 = 1024, nT1 = 8*n1
   ...
end subroutine skip
```

As a general remark on variable declaration I would like to make the following remarks:

- use `implicit none` as default. It makes debugging easier
- avoid star notation, it is not part of the standard for anything but characters, and for characters it is declared obsolescent.
- make use of `kind` parameters declared in the intrinsic module `iso_fortran_env`
- be aware that `double precision` does not necessarily mean "double precision" in the literal or IEEE sense of the word. It just means, twice the storage of a `real` and a higher precision than `real`. (a higher precision could be one-digit).

Answer (score 1):

You can define a parameter of a specific kind with

```
TYPE, PARAMETER :: name = value_kind
```

So to define, say, an integer n1 with kind INTEGER_TYPE you do

```
integer(kind=INTEGER_TYPE), parameter :: n1 = 1024_INTEGER_TYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an answer which gives the best way to specify the kind of a named constant.  You can find much more detail around [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/838310/3157076).

However, I'll add some detail about the `parameter` statement.

The `parameter` statement makes an object a named constant and specifies its value.  It doesn't specify the type or kind of that object.

The example of the question uses implicit typing for `n1` and `nT1`.  These are implicitly default integer.

The implicit rule may be changed (I won't show how), but the type may also be given explicitly:

```
integer(INTEGER_TYPE) n1, nT1
parameter (n1=1024, nT1=8*n1)
```

Still, the form of the other answer is preferable.  And, as noted there, the kind of the literal constants may also be given in the `parameter` statement if desired.